# Postgresql upgrade between major versions without downtime

Tags: postgresql

Is there any recommended way to upgrade between different postgresql versions (say, 9.2 to 9.3) without downtime?

Comment: Do you have more than one server?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, many actually.

Comment: Many postgres servers in a cluster, or many individual ones not hooked up to each other?

Comment: Both, 4 servers per cluster (one postgresql instance per server), many spares we can give any use.

Comment: There are essentially identical questions to this on dba.stackexchange.com.